# Cannot get delete request to work - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this route:

```
delete 'basket/remove' => 'flowercard_baskorder#remove', as: :basket_remove
```

This link in view:

```
<%= link_to "Remove", basket_remove_path %>
```

And this in my controller (the binding is just for me to test):

```
def remove
   binding.pry

end
```

When the link is clicked on nothing happens and i have no idea why!? I'm obviosuly expecting the binding to kick in but doesn't even look like a request is made?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) defaults to a get request but you want it to go to a delete right?  Just specify that in your call:

```
<%= link_to "Remove", basket_remove_path, method: :delete %>
```

Comment: Only by 18 seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the method to the `link_to` function

```
<%= link_to "Remove", basket_remove_path, method: "delete" %>
```